# Migrate standalone Mongo DBs to sharded/replicated cluster

Tags: mongodb

Currently I have several independent standalone Mongo servers. I have Now set up a sharded and replicated Mongo cluster. I plan to copy over all databases from the standalone Mongo servers to the cluster that has now been set up. What is the best way of accomplishing this transition?

Mongodumps and restores would work, but would be pretty slow. There is the possibility of copying data directories. Maybe it is possible to temporarily add a standalone server as a shard and wait for the things to balance then take down the shard? Perhaps the same method but with replica sets?

Comment: mongodump and restore would be the most straightforward way of accomplishing this. Have you benchmarked how long it would take? If restoring to a sharded collection I would recommend pre-splitting chunks as well so that your writes are divided across your shards (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/)